# Using ConceptNet5 API to calculate the similarity between texts

Tags: word2vec, cosine-similarity, conceptnet

I have found the ConceptNet5 API can be used to calculate the similarity between two terms with each other, for example:
http://api.conceptnet.io/related/c/en/dog?filter=/c/en/cat/.&limit=1

However I was wondering if the API can also be used to calculate the similarity between two texts. For example can I use the API to calculate the similarity between the following:

"The sea is blue"

"The mountain is white"